# iPhone issue of react-select

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-select

In iPhone react-select dropdown is moving to left , it is not aligning with select input of react-select

this is happening when we click  some other input tag and then verify react select, dropdown will move to left

```
const menuPortalTarget = menuTarget === null ? menuTarget : document.body;
const colorStyles = {
    dropdownIndicator: (base) => ({
        ...base,
        padding: 0,
    }),
    placeholder: (base, state) => ({
        ...base,
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        color: "#555",
        fontSize: "14px",
    }),
    indicatorSeparator: (provided) => ({
        ...provided,
        marginBottom: "0px",
        marginTop: "0px",
    }),
    valueContainer: (styles) => {
        return {
         ...styles,
         fontSize: '14px',
         padding: '14px',
         backgroundColor: isDisabled && "#eee",
        };
    },
    singleValue: (styles) => {
        return {
            ...styles,
            //height: "15px",
        }
    },
    menuList: (provided) => ({
        ...provided,
        maxHeight: height ? height : provided.maxHeight,
    }),
    control: (provided) => {
        return {
            ...provided,
            borderRadius: '0',
            '&:hover': {
                // border: '0',
            },
            width: width || "50%",
            minHeight: height,
            backgroundColor: "#fff",
            boxShadow: "none",
            border: selectedValue !== null ? "1px solid #4b7c4b" : (selectedValue === null && errorMessage !== '') ? "1px solid #a94442" : "1px solid #ccc",
            marginBottom: errorMessage !== '' ? '20px' : '25px',
            '@media(max-width:767.98px)': {
                width: "95%",
            },
        };
    },
    option: (provided, state) => ({
        ...provided,
        backgroundColor: state.isFocused && state.isDisabled ? '#aaa' : state.isFocused ? "rgba(56, 155, 236, 0.7)" : "white",
        ':active': {
            ...provided[':active'],
            backgroundColor: state.isDisabled ? "white" : state.isFocused ? provided[':active'].backgroundColor : 'blue',
        },
        padding: "3px 12px",
        backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
        backgroundPositionX: 'right',
        backgroundPositionY: 'center',
        // color: 'black',
        overflowY: 'hidden',
        fontSize: '14px',
        fontWeight: "400",
        color: state.isFocused ? "white" : "#555",
    }),
    menuPortal: base => ({
        ...base,
        zIndex: 999,
    }),
    menu: (provided) => ({
        ...provided,
        '@media(max-width:767.98px)': {
          width: menuPortalTarget === null ? width : "280px",
       },
        '@media only screen and(max-width: 768px)':{
            position:"absolute"
        },
        width: menuPortalTarget === null ? width : "100%",
    }),
};

return (
    <>
        <Select
            components={{ DropdownIndicator: customDropdown }}
            width={width}
            styles={colorStyles}
            onChange={onChange}
            value={value?.value ? { label: value.label, value: value.value } : undefined}
            data-index={index}
            selectedValue={selectedValue}
            placeholder="Please select"
            options={options}
            isDisabled={isDisabled}
            closeMenuOnSelect={true}
            aria-label={ariaLabel}
            menuPortalTarget={menuPortalTarget}
            menuPosition={menuPosition}
            menuPlacement='auto'
            isSearchable={false}
            closeMenuOnScroll={() => closeMenuOnScroll ? false : true}
        />
```

I have given `position: fixed` for menu styles and its not working.

Comment: Can you create any sandbox for this?